# I would like to plot a circular dendrogram with R

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot a circular dendrogram using R with the following tabular data:

| Fruit | Size | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Large | Red |
| Pear | Large | Green |
| Apple | Medium | Red |
| Pear | Large | Green |
| Apple | Medium | Yellow |
| Pear | Large | Green |
| Apple | Large | Green |
| Pear | Medium | Green |
| Apple | Large | Red |
| Pear | Medium | Yellow |

Ideally the interior would be the first column, the next layer would be the second, and the final layer the third.

I am not sure how I would plot this type of graphical representation using R. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is an example of what I am thinking of:
[image]

Comment: packages {circlize}, {igraph} and {ggraph} might be helpful: https://jokergoo.github.io/circlize_book/, https://r-graph-gallery.com/339-circular-dendrogram-with-ggraph.html, https://r.igraph.org/